# How to Verify if WebTAble is below the Webelement in QTP

Tags: qtp

there are two webtables suppose named as table1 and table2 and two webelements suppose named element1 and element2
I want to check if table1 should be below element1 and
table2 should be below element2.

I also want to verify some objects like buttons in that webpage are aligned left
Please help in UI related scripting part

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

Take the (x,y) coordinate of the table1 and (x,y) coordinate of Webelement element1
compare the Values of x value of webtable with x value of webelement same for y also.

if ( x1 > x2 ) we can say that table1 is below the element1  or Viceversa..

Similarliy with table2 and element2

Note.

Application should be in maximize mode. for maximising use below code.

```
            Set objIE= CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
                objIE.visible = True
                objIE.navigate strURL
                objIE.statusbar=1
                Window("hwnd:=" & objIE.HWND).Maximize
```

Answer (score 0):

Use visual identifier feature. Create objects for both the tables and their elements in object repository. Set the visual relation identifier to "Inline vertically"  and select the element you expect to see below the table. Hope this helps.